# An efficient way to store monthly recurring data that does not change frequently?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, recurring-events

I'm trying to find an efficient way to store monthly recurring data that does not change frequently.

```
class Fund < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :factsheets
end

class Factsheet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fund
end
```

A Fund will have a new Factsheet **per month**.

Each Factsheet have an objective on it (very long text, suppose).

The objective may **change** each month, but **not frequently** (say, change once per ~10 months).

Any good way to store the objective?

**Option 1:**

Put objective into model Factsheet, and it will duplicate a lot.

(store 12 objectives for 12 months, but most of them may be exactly the same)

**Option 2:**

Make objective a model, then Fund `has_many :objectives`

```
class Objective < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fund
end
```

Objective will have a column `:effective_on` to indicate: from which month a Fund should use this Objective record on its Factsheet.

(store 2 objectives for 12 months if only changed once)

**Option 3:**

Better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go the simplest option in your case, which is the first one.

Now why? My motivation is scale. Option 2 is a common case of over-engineering in my view. You'll have roughly **1200 records** on one table in **100 years**, and let's assume for the sake of the argument that the objective **never** change: you'd get 1200 entries in the DB that are duplicated.

Is that a big deal? I think not. For this scale, I believe a bit of duplication is perfectly tolerable.

If you were to create an entry every second, we could argue for a better solution, but I'd advise you to go with the simplest solution and concentrate on a problem that really does need some well-engineered solutions :).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 2... Because that is the real relationship in the real world just as you explain it. The verbalization that "a fund `has_many :objectives`" calls for objectives to be a model. Doing it this way also accommodates for flexibility in the future... perhaps objectives can belong to other models?

If you use option 2 you can then do something like `Fund.last.objectives` and see all of the objectives for the last Fund, whereas the first solution does not easily allow for such flexibility... you would have to do `Fund.where('created_at > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_year).pluck(:objective)` .... The second options is a lot cleaner, and it is certainly not "over engineering" anything.